# Is there an SQLite sample app for Uno Platform?

Tags: uno-platform

is there, by any chance, a sample app that illustrates the use of an SQLite database across all 4 Uno supported o/s platforms?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Uno team did this https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.SQLitePCLRaw.Wasm a while ago. It's using an old version of Uno (should be updated soon), but it's clearly showing how it can work on all platforms.